# Dictionary with list of tuples Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
if match:
   occur=0
   for item in tweets:
       if candidate in item:
          popular=item[4]+item[5]
          occur+=popular
          famous.append(occur)
return occur
```

I get 10161 only. Also for this function is there a way i can sort the list by numbers and return a list with candidates according the sorted number

Comment: and what result did you expect or want from your function?

Comment: @Copperfield so if the date is between the two dates, im goanna add a code that sees who's famous(by adding last two numbers) and will print out a list with people from greatest to least famous

Comment: ...ok, but that don't answer my question, what is this function supposed to do? return a list with the persons that fulfill the condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the modification are simple, first you need to create a empty list where the result will be keep, then in the for loop you need to check if the condition is fulfilled and add that element to the list if its does, and finally return that list. I also choose some more meaningful variables names

```
def famous(data_tweet, lower, higher ):
    result=[]
    for person, tweets in data_tweet.items():
        if all( lower <= tw[2] <= higher for tw in tweets ):
            result.append( person )
    return result
```

this can be reduced a little bit with the use of [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions)

```
def famous(data_tweet, lower, higher ):
    return [person for person, tweets in data_tweet.items() if all( lower <= tw[2] <= higher for tw in tweets )]
```

(notice the similarities)

in either case the result is

```
>>> famous(tweet,1470000000,1480000000)
['b', 'a']
>>>
```

---

As you are not allow to use `all`, then it should be done old school style, that is using flag, which is a variable which will tell us if the condition is fulfilled or not

```
def famous(data_tweet, lower, higher ):
    result=[]
    for person, tweets in data_tweet.items():
        is_valid = True
        for tw in tweets:
            if not ( lower <= tw[2] <= higher):
                is_valid = False
                break
        if is_valid:
            result.append( person )
    return result
```

here we first assume that the condition is fulfilled, then we check is that is effectively true, and if is not we change our flag to false and break that loop as there is no more reason to continue with further checks, which is the basically what [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) do for you. Afterwards, according to the value of the flag we append the person to the list or not.

(If you also are not allow to use [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement) either, don't worry and just remove it, that would not affect the function)

---

about the counting stuff

```
result=[]
for person in tweet:
    count = 0
    for tw in tweet[person]:
        count += tw[4] + tw[5]
    result.append(count)
```

Comment: copperfield is there a way to do it without using all?

Comment: yes, but that would be boil down to rewrite `all`, why you don't want to use it?

Comment: even if is part of the standard set of function of the language? well, anyway give a minute...

Comment: can you check my update problem, i would have made a new question, but i cant ask any more questions :(

Comment: you need to define a counter, to which you add the value of those number for each tweet of each person. That is similar to what I do with `is_valid`

Comment: Copper field but how will I do a counter (is_valid) cuz I'm not seeing if it's higher or lower I'm just adding

Comment: I said similar, not equal, first define your counter and make it equal to zero (`counter=0`) then iterate over the list of tweets of the particular person and do `counter = counter + number` where number is whatever you need to count, that couple of numbers in your case, when that is done add the counter your list. Repeat that for each person

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: the tweet I use is the original one, the dictionary... other than that  I don't know what other crazy stuff you are doing...

Comment: oh k lol i thought u mean tweets the value, also is there a way i can sort the list by numbers and return a list with candidates according the sorted number

Comment: yes, 2 option [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) or [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted). And to know which number belong to each person, instead of appending just the count, append `(count, person)`, and I leave as homework to you to answer why that particular arrange and not other

Comment: also append only uses 1 argument, so how can i add the person to it

Comment: like this: `result.append( (count,person) )`, that way you append a tuple of 2 elements...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129743/discussion-between-copperfield-and-cavs).